# How do I earn the "Well Done" achievement?

Tags: achievements, the-cave

There is an achievement in *The Cave* that I'm struggling with. It's called "Well Done" and the text reads thusly:

> Sacrificed oneself for ultimate flavor.

My first thought was getting myself burnt by the beast in the gift shop area, whilst holding a hot dog, of course. Sadly, it didn't work. Then I tried pushing the dragon's food bowl to the dragon so that he could set it, and me, on fire. Again, sadly, I was unable to push the bowl far enough. Nothing else comes to mind as potentially achievement-esque later in the game, which leaves me completely out of ideas.

**How do I earn this achievement?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to throw the hot dog onto the spike, and then jump OVER the pit to the other side, so that the beast burns you and THEN the hotdog (which is behind you.)

This video shows it in detail - it is for the xbox version, but in my experience, it works the same way. (I just tested it in my game.)